# How can I configure Windows 7 to do absolutely nothing?

Tags: windows-7

I have machine with old Windows 2000 Server. I would not recommend using it today for not experienced people, because it is extremely vulnerable to viruses released after Microsoft stopped support for this OS. However - for me Windows 2000 Server still works very well as file server (behind properly configured firewall and security options).

In this "retro" operating system it is not that hard to reach "computer state" when it does exactly nothing and it is not using disk, CPU etc.

If I have no "user sofware" running - hard disks turn off and they can stay turned off for days until I move mouse and wake up monitor (I have set "stop hard disk rotation" after 5 minutes).

---

**How can I configure Windows 7 to reach similar computer state?**

So far I have:

- turned off Windows Search
- turned off Windows Update
- turned off services installed by Google, Adobe and other "user sofware"
- turned off automatic defragmentation

---

I want to do it to keep my fileserver quiet, cool, improve my knowledge about Windows 7 and have maximum control over my operating system.

Comment: Why would you want that? Do you want to run it like a server? Or… let me guess, you probably want to [conserve your SSD life](http://superuser.com/questions/842286/how-can-i-measure-how-much-data-i-write-daily)?

Comment: @slhck I added explanation in my question.

Comment: Take a look at all the power management options

Comment: @DavidPostill I know how to configure power options. The problem is, that Windows 7 wakes up my disks.

Comment: MCE Standby Tool could help you find out.  There is a beta version for Win7.  http://slicksolutions.eu/mst.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can set your computer to go to sleep, and allow the NIC to wake him up (even without a magic packet) as shown here (Control panel > Network connections (also Run > ncpa.cpl) > properties > Configure > Power management).

[image: Wake on network]